# .Net Core 3.1 Entity Framework Slow Query Problem

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

There was slowness in my .net core webapi application, I reviewed and redesigned my queries to resolve this issue. The code snippet below was written to bring in sales, payments for sales, and sales territories.

I first include the condition query and then the sub-entities in the query. Then I choose which columns to work with ".Select()".

Then I want to combine this table with the name information in other tables. For example, information such as Customer Name, Product Name is in the other table.

***The first block of code I share below is a slow running linq query.***

```cs
result.Results = 
    (from s in context.Sales
    join sa in context.SaleProductServiceAreas on s.SaleId equals sa.SaleId
    join sp in context.SalePayments on s.SaleId equals sp.SaleId into spleft
    from sp in spleft.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join c in context.Customers on s.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId
    join p in context.ProductServices on s.ProductServiceId equals p.ProductServiceId
    where s.Date >= firstDayOfMonth && s.Date <= lastDayOfMonth
    group s by
    new
    {
        s.SaleId,
        s.CustomerId,
        CustomerNameSurname = c.Name + ' ' + c.Surname,
        ProductServiceName = p.Name,
        s.Date,
        s.Total,
        s.Session,
        p.ProductServiceId
    } into grp
    select new SaleJoinDto()
    {
        SaleId = grp.Key.SaleId,
        CustomerNameSurname = grp.Key.CustomerNameSurname,
        ProductServiceName = grp.Key.ProductServiceName,
        Total = grp.Key.Total,
        Date = grp.Key.Date,
        Session = grp.Key.Session,
        CustomerId = grp.Key.CustomerId,
        ProductServiceId = grp.Key.ProductServiceId,
        SaleProductServiceAreas = (from sps in context.SaleProductServiceAreas
                                    join spa in context.ProductServiceAreas on sps.ProductServiceAreaId equals spa.ProductServiceAreaId
                                    where sps.SaleId == grp.Key.SaleId
                                    select new SaleProductServiceAreaJoinDto()
                                    {
                                        SaleProductServiceAreaId = sps.SaleProductServiceAreaId,
                                        ProductServiceAreaName = spa.Name,
                                        ProductServiceAreaId = sps.ProductServiceAreaId,
                                        SaleId = sps.SaleId
                                    }).ToList(),
        SalePayments = (from spp in context.SalePayments
                        where spp.SaleId == grp.Key.SaleId
                        select new SalePaymentDto()
                        {

                            SaleId = spp.SaleId,
                            SalePaymentId = spp.SalePaymentId,
                            Total = spp.Total,
                            PaymentMethod = spp.PaymentMethod,
                            Date = spp.Date
                        }).ToList()

    }).ToList();
```

["**NEW**"] ***This query I wrote is the query I rewrite as a result of the articles I have shared below.***

[Document of Microsoft Link for query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/extraneous-fetching/)

```cs
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var result = new PagedResult<SaleJoinDto>();
    result.CurrentPage = pageNumber;
    result.PageSize = pageSize;
    var pageCount = (double)result.RowCount / pageSize;
    result.PageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(pageCount);
    var skip = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;


    var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
    var lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

    result.Results = await context.Sales
        .Where(x => x.Date >= firstDayOfMonth && x.Date <= lastDayOfMonth)
        .Include(x => x.SalePayments)
        .Include(x => x.SaleProductServiceAreas)
    .Select(s => new Sale()
    {
        SaleId = s.SaleId,
        CustomerId = s.CustomerId,
        Date = s.Date,
        Total = s.Total,
        Session = s.Session,
        SalePayments = s.SalePayments,
        SaleProductServiceAreas = s.SaleProductServiceAreas
    })
    .Join(context.Customers, sales => sales.CustomerId, customers => customers.CustomerId, (sales, customers) => new
    {
        sales,
        customers
    })
    .Join(context.ProductServices, combinedSaleAndCus => combinedSaleAndCus.sales.ProductServiceId, product => product.ProductServiceId, (combinedSaleAndCus, product) => new SaleJoinDto()
    {
        SaleId = combinedSaleAndCus.sales.SaleId,
        CustomerId = combinedSaleAndCus.sales.CustomerId,
        Date = combinedSaleAndCus.sales.Date,
        Total = combinedSaleAndCus.sales.Total,
        Session = combinedSaleAndCus.sales.Session,
        CustomerNameSurname = combinedSaleAndCus.customers.Name,
        SalePayments = combinedSaleAndCus.sales.SalePayments.Select(x => new SalePaymentDto()
        {
            Date = x.Date,
            PaymentMethod = x.PaymentMethod,
            SaleId = x.SaleId,
            SalePaymentId = x.SalePaymentId,
            Total = x.Total
        }).ToList(),
        SaleProductServiceAreas = combinedSaleAndCus.sales.SaleProductServiceAreas.Join(context.ProductServiceAreas, sp => sp.ProductServiceAreaId, psa => psa.ProductServiceAreaId, (sp, psa) => new SaleProductServiceAreaJoinDto()
        {
            SaleProductServiceAreaId = sp.SaleProductServiceAreaId,
            ProductServiceAreaName = psa.Name
        }).ToList()
    })
    .ToListAsync();

    result.RowCount = result.Results.Count();

    result.Results = result.Results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

The problem is I do get the following error when I rewrite it according to this new query.
Where am I making a mistake in the query I just wrote?

> {"The LINQ expression 'DbSet\r\n    .Where(s => s.Date >=
> __firstDayOfMonth_0 && s.Date <= __lastDayOfMonth_1)\r\n    .Join(\r\n        outer: DbSet, \r\n        inner: s => s.CustomerId, \r\n
> outerKeySelector: c => c.CustomerId, \r\n        innerKeySelector: (s,
> c) => new TransparentIdentifier<Sale, Customer>(\r\n            Outer
> = s, \r\n            Inner = c\r\n        ))\r\n    .Join(\r\n        outer: DbSet, \r\n        inner: ti => new Sale{ \r\n
> SaleId = ti.Outer.SaleId, \r\n            CustomerId =
> ti.Outer.CustomerId, \r\n            Date = ti.Outer.Date, \r\n
> Total = ti.Outer.Total, \r\n            Session = ti.Outer.Session,
> \r\n            SalePayments = (MaterializeCollectionNavigation(\r\n
> navigation: Navigation: Sale.SalePayments,\r\n
> subquery: DbSet\r\n                    .Where(s0 =>
> EF.Property(ti.Outer, "SaleId") != null &&
> EF.Property(ti.Outer, "SaleId") == EF.Property(s0,
> "SaleId"))), \r\n            SaleProductServiceAreas =
> (MaterializeCollectionNavigation(\r\n                navigation:
> Navigation: Sale.SaleProductServiceAreas,\r\n                subquery:
> DbSet\r\n                    .Where(s1 =>
> EF.Property(ti.Outer, "SaleId") != null &&
> EF.Property(ti.Outer, "SaleId") == EF.Property(s1,
> "SaleId"))) \r\n        }\r\n        .ProductServiceId, \r\n
> outerKeySelector: p => p.ProductServiceId, \r\n
> innerKeySelector: (ti, p) => new
> TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<Sale, Customer>,
> ProductService>(\r\n            Outer = ti, \r\n            Inner =
> p\r\n        ))'
> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in
> a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation
> explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(),
> AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more
> information."}

Comment: What is it saying "could not be translated"? That's usually caused by a `.Where` or similar expression which is invoking a method that cannot be directly translated to SQL by the EF provider.

Comment: Grouping magically disappear in second query?

Comment: I shared the whole error again. @MattU

Comment: As with the linq query, I cannot group 3 tables at the same time, so after selecting the columns I will use, I join them one by one. @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: As it says in the document, it writes stay away from nested and multiple queries. So I have to make it all into one query.

Comment: You group not tables but query and it is not a problem. Why you have used grouping in first variant?

Comment: The product name and customer name information are in the other table, since I used the join statement at the beginning of the query and I needed the name information, I had to add it to the group. @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: One of your expressions cannot be translated to SQL by EF. I suspect it's the `.Where(x => x.Date >= firstDayOfMonth && x.Date <= lastDayOfMonth)` so you may have to find a different way to calculate the first and last day of the month. Try that and see what happens.

Comment: When I remove the where statement, the result does not change. @MattU

Comment: It worked when I removed the Select statement from the query. But the link below says use only what you need. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/extraneous-fetching/#how-to-fix-extraneous-fetching-antipattern

Comment: Which `Select` did you remove?

Comment: I removed the select line after the include statement. @MattU

Comment: In the first query the GroupBy was the problem. The second query is totally different and the syntax nor the amount of data fectched is an improvement despite the link you seem to have followed. It's all about the GroupBy. Also, don't join, use navigation properties and the query will shrink to a few lines.

Comment: I understand that using groupby poses a problem. For the second query, you said not to use join, can you give an example of how I can access the relevant features without using join? @GertArnold

Comment: Since you said don't use join expression, I have done some research and I'm very confused about it. Is there a performance difference between include and join? If so, which one should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the slow responsiveness of the app.
I was running the application on windows host. I changed my hosting to Centos 7 which is a linux distribution. Then when I run the application on Centos 7, the application accelerated perfectly and took flight.

My advice to all .net Core app developers, migrate your apps to linux. It is built to run on .net core linux distributions.

I share the problems I encountered while migrating the application to linux and how I solved it in the link below.

[.Net Core 3.1 deploy on Centos 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67746545/net-core-3-1-deploy-on-centos-7/67756174#67756174)

Comment: I don't think changing OS would drastically improve performance like what you're describing. Your issue was most probably hardware-related.

Comment: same hardware, same ram, same processor, how could it be hardware related? @Laurent

Comment: Windows hosting consumes 5gb ram, while centos 7 only consumes 300mb. @Laurent

Comment: I don't see how having 5 GB of RAM usage would impact CPU performance.

Comment: my server was windows hosting and it was wasting 4gb ram on its own. As a result of my research on the internet, when I installed centos 7 and installed my .net core application, the system accelerated tremendously. @Laurent

Comment: Well if that worked for you then great, but it seems more likely that there was a configuration error somewhere in your Windows instance, or a misunderstanding of the specs of the VM you were using.

Answer (score 1):

Removed not needed joins and grouping. It should be faster.

```cs
var query =
    from s in context.Sales
    join c in context.Customers on s.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId
    join p in context.ProductServices on s.ProductServiceId equals p.ProductServiceId
    where s.Date >= firstDayOfMonth && s.Date <= lastDayOfMonth
    select new SaleJoinDto()
    {
        SaleId = s.SaleId,
        CustomerNameSurname = c.Name + ' ' + c.Surname,
        ProductServiceName = p.ProductServiceName,
        Total = s.Total,
        Date = s.Date,
        Session = s.Session,
        CustomerId = s.CustomerId,
        ProductServiceId = p.ProductServiceId,
        SaleProductServiceAreas = (from sps in context.SaleProductServiceAreas
                                    join spa in context.ProductServiceAreas on sps.ProductServiceAreaId equals spa.ProductServiceAreaId
                                    where sps.SaleId == s.SaleId
                                    select new SaleProductServiceAreaJoinDto()
                                    {
                                        SaleProductServiceAreaId = sps.SaleProductServiceAreaId,
                                        ProductServiceAreaName = spa.Name,
                                        ProductServiceAreaId = sps.ProductServiceAreaId,
                                        SaleId = sps.SaleId
                                    }).ToList(),
        SalePayments = (from spp in context.SalePayments
                        where spp.SaleId == s.SaleId
                        select new SalePaymentDto()
                        {

                            SaleId = spp.SaleId,
                            SalePaymentId = spp.SalePaymentId,
                            Total = spp.Total,
                            PaymentMethod = spp.PaymentMethod,
                            Date = spp.Date
                        }).ToList()

    };

result.Results = query.ToList();
```

Anyway, even joins can be simplified if you have navigation properties which are not shown in original question.

Comment: When I test it on the server, it keeps waiting for 10 seconds occasionally, where is the problem?

Comment: Problem is `SaleProductServiceAreas` and `SalePayments`. It creates cartesian explosion for the returned records.

Comment: I'm moving the application from .net core 3.1 to 5.0, then I'll try again. The slowness problem happens occasionally when requests are thrown back to back.

Comment: It will not help  ;)

Comment: Anyway, if you have time, try our extension https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore and just call `ToLinqToDB()` before `ToList()`.

Comment: Does your solution solve the slowness problem? I urgently need to figure out why it is slowing down from time to time.

Comment: It uses splitting query approach for Eager Loading.

Comment: Could the problem be with the operating system? Is it worth trying to switch from windows to linux?

Comment: Nope, it is how EF works and how it creates queries.

Comment: .net core identity is also running slow, I wait a lot when logging in.

Comment: Monitor generated SQL. It is unusual situation. Also it can be problem with bad `async` usage. Yesterday I have found `Task.Resut` call which slowed down everything.

Comment: I removed all the async methods, it affected the performance to some extent.

Comment: I solved the slow response problem of the application.

Comment: Well, this query is memory consuming because of cartesian explosion . BUT why you have not tried my extension? ;)

Comment: Actually, the whole problem was that it was windows hosting, when I format it to centos 7 and install it, the system accelerated tremendously. Previously, all queries took an average of 10 seconds, upgrading to centos 7, all queries are completed in 0.002 to 0.001 milliseconds.

Comment: More looks like bad `async` usage. It's realisation is different between OS.

Comment: I tried after removing all async methods, windows hosting does not change the result is the same.