# .Net Core 3.1 deploy on Centos 7

Tags: linux, apache, asp.net-core, nginx, centos

I am trying to run my .net Core web api application on Centos 7 + Plesk server. My application will be running in the subdomain. I set up a subdomain from the Plesk panel and transferred my files. After, I followed the article below step by step, it is not a very explanatory or helpful article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-3.1

First of all, this path does not exist /etc/nginx/sites-available/default. So with the help of other articles, I created the file api.mysite.com.conf in the etc/nginx/conf.d folder.

> To configure Nginx as a reverse proxy to forward HTTP requests to your
> ASP.NET Core app, modify /etc/nginx/sites-available/default. Open it
> in a text editor, and replace the contents with the following snippet.

```
    server {
        listen        80;
        server_name   api.mysite.com *.mysite.com;
        location / {
             .... same as in docs.
        }
    }
```

Secondly, I created the service file by following the document. "/usr/bin/dotnet" This directory does not exist at this step, the document is not surprising again.

I solved this step by typing "/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet" instead of "/usr/bin/dotnet".

> sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/kestrel-webapi.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Centos 7

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/api.mysite.com
ExecStart=/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/api.mysite.com
```

After creating the service, I ran it without any problems.

The next step was Apache configuration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-3.1

> Configuration files for Apache are located within the
> /etc/httpd/conf.d/ directory. Any file with the .conf extension is
> processed in alphabetical order in addition to the module
> configuration files in /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/, which contains any
> configuration files necessary to load modules.

I'm creating a configuration file in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" file.

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=${REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias *.mysite.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}webapi-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}webapi-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

After making this configuration, I got an error while running the following commands in order.

> sudo service httpd configtest

> sudo systemctl restart httpd

```
[Fri May 28 19:35:02.344213 2021] [core:warn] [pid 25339:tid 139880432744576] AH00111: Config variable ${REQUEST_SCHEME} is not defined
[Fri May 28 19:35:02.344814 2021] [core:warn] [pid 25339:tid 139880432744576] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Fri May 28 19:35:02.344853 2021] [core:warn] [pid 25339:tid 139880432744576] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
Syntax OK


May 28 19:39:16 localhost.localdomain httpd[25740]: [Fri May 28 19:39:16.897163 2021] [core:warn] [pid 25740:tid 140630647605376] AH00111: Config variable ${REQUEST_SCHEME} is not defined
May 28 19:39:16 localhost.localdomain httpd[25740]: [Fri May 28 19:39:16.897775 2021] [core:warn] [pid 25740:tid 140630647605376] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
May 28 19:39:16 localhost.localdomain httpd[25740]: [Fri May 28 19:39:16.897825 2021] [core:warn] [pid 25740:tid 140630647605376] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
May 28 19:39:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 28 19:39:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
May 28 19:39:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
May 28 19:39:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Before doing these operations, when I opened api.mysite.com through the browser, the plesk panel welcome page was displayed. I solved this problem by writing the following code, now I am getting 403 forbidden error.

```
mv /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf_backup
```

How do I solve the above two problems? How can I redirect to my web api application when I connect to api.mysite.com?

I've been struggling with this for 3 days and I can't find the right articles on the internet, is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: I need help, I could'nt do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.
When we create a domain in the plesk panel, apache creates its own configuration file, so all I have to do is change the Additional apache directives settings from within Apache & nginx under the Hosting & DNS settings of the relevant domain from the plesk panel.

Plesk --> Websites & Domains --> <> --> Hosting & DNS --> Apache & nginx

**Additional directives for HTTP**

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://yourdomain.com"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, 
X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-ControlRequest-Headers, Authorization, Content-Disposition"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

**Additional directives for HTTPS**

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://yourdomain.com"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, 
X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-ControlRequest-Headers, Authorization, Content-Disposition"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

***If you have a cors problem, you can add lines starting with header set.***

After doing all these, your application will run if it is ready in your service file.